# Reading form local file and save into variable

Tags: javascript, file

I've got .txt file with many many words and want to open it in javascript (localy on PC) and save all content into string/array. Found solution with getScriptFile but it didn't run. Any ideas?:)
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this in a web browser or in Node?

Comment: _"Found solution with getScriptFile but it didn't run"_ -- So where is it? How did you debug it? What didn't work?

Comment: If something doesn't work it barely can be named a "solution"